# Apache 2.4 + php7 + MySql

Tags: php, mysql, apache

Доброго всем времени суток.

Решил развернуть в ручную апач + пхп + бд.

Настроил, вроде как работает но одна загвоздка, хотел прописать в файле httpd-vhosts.conf алиасы для локалхоста и для пхпмюадмин, но тут апач не захотел запускаться...

Как только коментирую все строки то все запускается и все работает вот только в пхпмюадмин попасть я не могу.

Пробовал по разному, и отключать библиотеки и включать все-равно одно и тоже.

**Скидываю лог**

```
(20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: AH00097: Invalid PID file path \xe2\x80\x9cC:/PhpServer/web/apache/logs/httpd.pid\xe2\x80\x9d, ignoring.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/PhpServer/web/php/ext\\php_curl.dll' - \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Jun 26 12:26:08.010793 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5332:tid 676] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.1.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 26 12:26:08.010793 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5332:tid 676] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Mar 29 2018 12:12:07
[Tue Jun 26 12:26:08.010793 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5332:tid 676] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\PhpServer\\web\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/PhpServer/web/apache'
[Tue Jun 26 12:26:08.012787 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5332:tid 676] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7256
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:/PhpServer/web/php/ext\\php_curl.dll' - \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Jun 26 12:26:08.465272 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7256:tid 628] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Jun 26 12:38:22.251049 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5332:tid 676] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Jun 26 12:38:24.255161 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7256:tid 628] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Jun 26 12:38:24.289359 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5332:tid 676] AH00430: Parent: Child process 7256 exited successfully.
(20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: AH00097: Invalid PID file path \xe2\x80\x9cC:/PhpServer/web/apache/logs/httpd.pid\xe2\x80\x9d, ignoring.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\\PhpServer\\web\\php\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Jun 26 12:41:19.830120 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4812:tid 676] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.1.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 26 12:41:19.830120 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4812:tid 676] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Mar 29 2018 12:12:07
[Tue Jun 26 12:41:19.830120 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4812:tid 676] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\PhpServer\\web\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/PhpServer/web/apache'
[Tue Jun 26 12:41:19.831118 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4812:tid 676] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 2248
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\\PhpServer\\web\\php\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Jun 26 12:41:20.248217 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2248:tid 628] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Jun 26 12:41:25.954518 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4812:tid 676] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Jun 26 12:41:27.957429 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 2248:tid 628] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Jun 26 12:41:27.988431 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4812:tid 676] AH00430: Parent: Child process 2248 exited successfully.
(20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: AH00097: Invalid PID file path \xe2\x80\x9cC:/PhpServer/web/apache/logs/httpd.pid\xe2\x80\x9d, ignoring.
[Tue Jun 26 12:46:08.643818 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4480:tid 684] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.1.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 26 12:46:08.643818 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4480:tid 684] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Mar 29 2018 12:12:07
[Tue Jun 26 12:46:08.643818 2018] [core:notice] [pid 4480:tid 684] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\PhpServer\\web\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/PhpServer/web/apache'
[Tue Jun 26 12:46:08.644818 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4480:tid 684] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 6384
[Tue Jun 26 12:46:09.042110 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6384:tid 604] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
[Tue Jun 26 12:46:24.044684 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4480:tid 684] AH00422: Parent: Received shutdown signal -- Shutting down the server.
[Tue Jun 26 12:46:26.049395 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 6384:tid 604] AH00364: Child: All worker threads have exited.
[Tue Jun 26 12:46:26.065438 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 4480:tid 684] AH00430: Parent: Child process 6384 exited successfully.
(20024)The given path is misformatted or contained invalid characters: AH00097: Invalid PID file path \xe2\x80\x9cC:/PhpServer/web/apache/logs/httpd.pid\xe2\x80\x9d, ignoring.
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\\PhpServer\\web\\php\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Jun 26 12:59:11.118278 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5060:tid 676] AH00455: Apache/2.4.33 (Win64) PHP/7.1.19 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Tue Jun 26 12:59:11.118278 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5060:tid 676] AH00456: Apache Lounge VC14 Server built: Mar 29 2018 12:12:07
[Tue Jun 26 12:59:11.118278 2018] [core:notice] [pid 5060:tid 676] AH00094: Command line: 'C:\\PhpServer\\web\\apache\\bin\\httpd.exe -d C:/PhpServer/web/apache'
[Tue Jun 26 12:59:11.118278 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 5060:tid 676] AH00418: Parent: Created child process 7464
PHP Warning:  PHP Startup: Unable to load dynamic library 'c:\\PhpServer\\web\\php\\ext\\php_curl.dll' - \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd \xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd\xef\xbf\xbd.\r\n in Unknown on line 0
[Tue Jun 26 12:59:11.446311 2018] [mpm_winnt:notice] [pid 7464:tid 624] AH00354: Child: Starting 150 worker threads.
```

Не знаю почему, но Curl лежит на своем месте, а почему в логах пишется что его нету странно в пхпинфо тоже есть. Буду весьма благодарен за помощь.

Comment: Двойные кавычки в конфиге неправильные?

Comment: кавычки нормальные... тут дело в том что я вношу изменения в файл виртуальных хостингов и апач выдает ошибку... понять не могу где я делаю ошибку. уже настраивал по мануалу и все равно драконит меня.

Comment: Показывайте ваш файл настройки хоста.

Comment: Апач запустился. Эт я не внимательный. нужно было закрыть </virtualHost> а с октытым тегом пытался. Но вдруг другая ошибка выплыла немогу войти в пхпмюадмин в логах ошибка ""GET /phpmyadmin/ HTTP/1.1" 500 609"